# MongoDB Service on Ubuntu fails after upgrade

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem that is really really really messing me up! I've got so many headaches. I updated the MongoDB package on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine today morning and since then I have been unable to get it to start (mongod). I narrowed down the problem to find out that the mongod daemon is trying to load the data path at /data/db yet my mongo.conf specifically states that the path is at /var/lib/mongodb.

What is going on? When I run mongod and set the path directly then the service starts up without any problem. But I do not want to keep doing that everytime I want to start it up. Someone please help me. Am I missing something in the configurations? Thanks for time and assistance. The error I get when I look at the logs:

```
2018-02-01T15:22:27.879+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4989 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=sm
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-01T15:22:27.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-01T15:22:27.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-02-01T15:22:27.881+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2018-02-01T15:22:27.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-02-01T15:22:27.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

And part of my mongod.conf file is:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Thanks guys!

EDIT: Some would say I should create the data directory in /data/db but what will happen to the data that I already have in the lib directory :(

Comment: Where is the conf file located, and how are you specifying the `--config` value when starting `mongod`?

Comment: The conf file is located in the /etc folder (/etc/mongod.conf). When I type `sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongod` then the service starts successfully.

Comment: If you want to specify the config file instead, you can use `mongod --config /etc/mongo.conf` per [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file)

Comment: Thanks. When I try that command it hangs :( Not sure why. The log files don't report anything either.

Comment: :-(  hm... no more ideas regarding the config. As an aside, I have moved MongoDB data to other locations, and it's just fine. You could copy the data from `/var/lib/mongodb` to `/data/db`, and it should pick it up (assuming you've converted it to wiredTiger format, depending on what previous version you used).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and it  worked and then the path changed back to /var/lib/mongod. This is really strange. I think I might remove it all and reinstall, ofcourse saving my files first.